# SUM based on the column value

Tags: excel

I have a column with values like Physics and Chemistry, please refer below image for details. I want to add all the values against Physics and Chemistry. How to use "COUNTIF"?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Don't use COUNTIF, use SUMIF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are variety of way to achieve your result. As @BigBen suggested you use `SUMIFS()` like-

```
=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$5,$A$1:$A$5,D2)
```

You can use `SUMPRODUCT()` like-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$5)*($A$1:$A$5=D2))
```

Also `SUM()` function will work like-

```
=SUM(--($A$1:$A$5=D2)*($B$1:$B$5))
```

[image]